# jQuery/Rails setting default on document ready

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, default, pageload

So i have a list of anchor tags that I am using for a filter. I am using jQuery to look for the appropriate data tag so when a name is clicked it will show all the work that a developer has completed from a list of all completed items. What i would like to make it elegant, is to have it default to the current user. So if Mike logs in, that the anchor link for Mike is clicked.

```
<a data-filter="dev-mike" href="#">Mike</a>
<a data-filter="dev-john" href="#">John</a>
```

Is there a way to have jQuery activate or enable an anchor tag on page load?

Some ideas that I was thinking in case this isn't possible was to have rails give the anchor tag that belongs to the current user a new data attribute called `data-default`. but then I'll still have to have use jQuery to select that tag as active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is redirect the user to that page after logging in with an anchor at the end of the url. For example:

```
www.mywebsitelandingpage.com#mike
```

Then to select one tag as active on page load, you can do something like that:

```
<a data-filter="dev-mike" class="<%= 'current' if current_user.name == "Mike" %>" href="#mike">Mike</a>
<a data-filter="dev-john" class="<%= 'current' if current_user.name == "John" %>" href="#john">John</a>
```

and then of course use some CSS to style the a tag with `class="current"`

Comment: i ended up doing something simular. i just gave a new data tag called `data-default` and then called if current_user set `data-default`. then using the trigger function   `$('.filters a[data-default=default]').trigger('click');`